# HTML5 Compliant - Trailing Space in Class Attribute

Tags: html, validation, standards, classname, specifications

I know that technically HTML5 is a 'living spec' but I'm wondering if it's compliant to have trailing spaces inside of a class name. I didn't see any reference to this scenario in the spec, but one of my teammates said it was invalid. Maybe I missed something?

It'd be a pain to trim those spaces (I'm working inside of a large Java ecom application) and I want to know if it's worth doing for SEO, validation or any other purpose. I get the feeling it's not... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see in the link below, there is no restriction on what the developer can use in the class attribute.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes

In fact, after saying what the classes are and that they're used spliting in the spaces, the author(s) says:

> There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in
>   the class attribute, but authors are encouraged to use values that
>   describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe
>   the desired presentation of the content.

Our colleagues here have tested and it successfully passes W3C validation, so I can't guess why your friend thought it was invalid.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is compliant.

From 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes:

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a **set of space-separated tokens** representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

From 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens:

> A string containing a **set of space-separated tokens** may have leading or trailing space characters.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://validator.w3.org/ under a `<!DOCTYPE html>` the following validates successfully.

```
<div class=" name1 name2 "></div>
```

Leaving a trailing and leading space may be acceptable, but it's not pretty and some people do not consider it to be best a practice.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that knows how to handle class attributes should be fine with this. It is possible to give a tag multiple classes by separating them with spaces so anything which reads them had better know how to deal with spaces.