# Can I get away with adding a whitespace to a class definition?

Tags: html, css, class, syntax

I'm working on some legacy PHP code that, depending on conditions, produces either the following output:

```
<div class="foo bar">Bork bork bork</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="foo ">Bork bork bork</div>
```

Note the **whitespace following the class name** in the second example. Which is decidedly ugly, but I'm under some time constraints right now and fixing this will take some major code surgery that I'd rather avoid for the moment. On the browsers I've tested it so far there doesn't seem to be a problem, but if I'm committing an outright standards violation here, I'd rather put in the overtime tonight.

So. As per the standards, is this allowed?

Comment: It should be fine. The only potential issue that I can think of is if you're using the attribute selector `[class="foo"]` and whitespace would make a difference.. http://jsfiddle.net/p1pcxy25/ (but you really shouldn't be abusing the attribute selector like that.. so you're likely fine).

Comment: Duplication noted. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HTML5 Compliant - Trailing Space in Class Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439859/html5-compliant-trailing-space-in-class-attribute)

Yes, it is compliant

From 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes:

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a **set of space-separated tokens** representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

From 
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens:

> A string containing a **set of space-separated tokens** may have leading or trailing space characters.

Comment: @jezrael I don't understand, can you explain : Q: "Is it compliant?", A: "Yes, it is compliant and will work". Seems pretty clear.

Comment: Super, I maybe I found [explaining](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers).